# Running aplay via systemd

Tags: linux, systemd

As per [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1324582), I seem to be able to work around a problem with sound playback by running `aplay -f cd /dev/zero`. I've put the command into a script at `~/Scripts/openAudio`. I want the script to run from login. I've created this file at `/etc/systemd/system/openAudio.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=open the audio

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/gareth/Scripts/openAudio

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I did this:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable openAudio
sudo service openAudio start
```

The command `systemctl status openAudio` gives things like this and without aplay running:

```
× openAudio.service - open the audio
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/openAudio.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-01-30 13:06:38 GMT; 5s ago
   Duration: 18ms
    Process: 7951 ExecStart=/home/gareth/Scripts/openAudio (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 7951 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 17ms

Jan 30 13:06:38 bramall systemd[1]: Started openAudio.service - open the audio.
Jan 30 13:06:38 bramall openAudio[7952]: aplay: main:834: audio open error: Host is down
Jan 30 13:06:38 bramall systemd[1]: openAudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 30 13:06:38 bramall systemd[1]: openAudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Any suggestions for how to get the aplay command to run automatically from login?

EDIT: I've found a similar question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/675659), but sadly with no answer.